# How many lines for 80% of costs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file with 3000 hotels and I have the spends on each hotel. I would like to create a function to let me know how many hotels is necessary to make 80% of the total spend.

Until now, I had written on each line (in column AS): `AR4/SUM(AR:AR)`
And then I had cumulated it using: `AT3+AS4`
And finally on another cell: `COUNTIF(AT:AT,"<80%")+1`

However, this only works if my hotels are sorted by their respected spends. As soon as I change the order, it gives me wrong numbers (which is normal)

Do you guys know of any other method to solve this ? Thank you very much

Comment: You could quite easily solve that, using Excel's Solver add-in, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a formula solution....

Assuming spend data in AR2:AR3000 then use this formula in AS2 copied down to give a "unique rank"

`=RANK(AR2,AR$2:AR$3000)+COUNTIF(AR$2:AR2,AR2)-1`

Now use this "array formula" to get your answer

`=MATCH(SUM(AR:AR)*0.8,SUMIF(AS:AS,"<"&ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(AR:AR))),AR:AR))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`